Is this proof of Euclid's Lemma correct?
I managed to think of a proof of fundamental theorem of arithmetic using roots of unity however not too sure about it. Finding one factorization is easy, we just focus on uniqueness or on Euclid's lemma.

Euclid's lemma. Let $p$ be a prime and $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$. If $p \mid ab$ then $p \mid a$ or $p \mid b$.

Proof: Assume the contrary. We might also assume $a<p,b<p$.
Let $\omega$ be a primitive $p^{th}$ root of unity. [proving existence doesn't use fundamental theorem of arithmetic hopefully I hope]
as $p \mid ab$ we know that $\omega^{ab}=1$
then $(\omega^a)^{b}=1$
But then $p|b$ . [as we know $\omega^a$ is also a primtive root ].
However as like fundamental theorom of arethemtic is really fundamental i am not tooo sure if i am creating a circular reasoning somewhere .
I thought for a second I am assuming existence of primtive root.
However when you say let $t$ be the smallest positive integer such that $(\omega)^t=1$ then $t \mid p$ then $t=1,p$ by that you easily come to the result.
And for why $\omega^a$ is also a primitive root say $t$ is the smallest integer such that $(\omega^a)^{t}=1$. Assume it's not primitive then $t<p$ and $t \mid p$ so $t=1$.
So $\omega^a=1$, however that forces $p(x)=x^{p}-1$ to have a double root however checking its derivative we get an easy contradiction.

"we know $\omega^a$ is also a primtive root": I don't. "Assume its not primtive then $t<p$ and $t|p$": why $t\mid p$? "however that forces $p(x)=x^{p}-1$ has a double root": how so?

Assume the contrary  then let $r$ be the remainder when $p$ is divided by $t$ then $\omega^r=1$ for r will be something of form $p-tk$  and $0<r<t$ @AnneBauval

And as for the double root if $\omega^a=1$ and p did not divide $a$ we know 1 is a double root

Thank you, the first comment helped me. I still don't understand the second one.

Does this answer your question? If a prime $p\mid ab$, then $p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$ (Euclid's Lemma) Your proof is essentially correct. Bernard's answer in this link is not an alternative one. It is yours (up to exchanging $a$ and $b$), just simplified, thus made shorter than most of those on this site.

@Anne That "short" direct proof of Euclid's Lemma is the most common proof given in textbooks, and almost surely the most common proof on this site. The slightly longer proofs in some answers in the linked dupe (using ideas from the theory of ideals or cyclic groups) are pedagogically far superior if one goes on to study advanced number theory or abstract algebra, so one should not denigrate them.

I already knew you are conviced of this "far superiority", and I agree to disagree, as previously shortly explained.

Wait can u please explain a bit on what u said @BillDubuque i didnt quite understand

@Lucid What is your knowledge level? Which of these topics do your know:  congruences / modular arithmetic, groups, rings.

@Anne Please do tell what you think is "scary" about the first few paragraphs here, That can be understood by any high school student, and once they learn that fundamental Lemma they will be able to reapply it in many other common proofs (e.g. the gcd Bezout identity, the Order Theorem, etc). It will further serve as good intuition once they advance to the study of (cyclic) groups & (principal) ideals.

@BillDubuque i guess ik all of them , but group rings not at too advanced level
